# How to capture the whole query string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I want to capture all the query string which is coming from the back page into a string and throw as a Response.Redirect("myPage.aspx?ALL Query String Goes Here").

How should I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
string redirectURL = "http://www.example.com/myPage.aspx?" + Request.QueryString.ToString(); 
Response.Redirect(redirectURL);
```

Answer (score 5):

This will give you the raw querystring.

```
Request.Url.Query
```